# System giving me an eventID of 8003 source bowser

Tags: windows-vista

Log Name:      System
Source:        bowser
Date:          10/9/2009 8:12:31 PM
Event ID:      8003
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      [Insert Comp Name]
Description:
The master browser has received a server announcement from the computer [another comp] that believes that it is the master browser for the domain on transport NetBT_Tcpip_{[random string of numbers]. The master browser is stopping or an election is being forced.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1):

A browser election is a normal network occurrence and provides a means to guarantee there is never more than one master browser present in a domain or workgroup.

For more information look at this [Microsoft KB article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188001)